# Как в Dagger 2 заинжектить два разных scope одним махом?

Tags: android, dependency-injection

Положим, у нас есть два компонента в разных scope с разным же lifetime. В одном лежат чисто activity-specific вещи (SharedPreferences, всякие системные менеджеры, зависящие от Context), в другом — сессионная информация (текущий пользователь, токен, ID сессии и т.д.), т.е. чисто бизнес-инфо без привязки к Андроиду и контексту.

Скоупы живут разной жизнью, один может создаться раньше другого и наоборот, делать их подкомпонентами друг для друга не получается.

И вот появляется, например, presenter, в который нужно передать зависимости из этих двух компонентов. Что оба компонента будут готовы к этому моменту, это я могу гарантировать. Какие есть варианты заинжектить? Сделать третий подкомпонент нельзя, скоупы разные, Dagger ругается (даже если скоупы не имеют общего родителя). Перечислять в конструкторе презентера зависимости руками без аннотаций Inject?

```
layoutInflater = Injector.getViewComponent().getLayoutInflater();
currentSessionId = Injector.getSessionComponent().getSessionId();
```

Это получается весьма многословно. 
Разделить зависимости на два набора и поместить в отдельные классы внутри презентера?

```
public class Presenter {

    public static class SessionPart {
        @Inject
        protected String currentSessionId;

        public SessionPart() {
            Injector.getSessionComponent().inject(this);
        }
    }

    public static class ViewPart {
        @Inject
        protected LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        public ViewPart() {
            Injector.getViewComponent().inject(this);
        }
    }

    public Presenter() {
        s = new SessionPart();
        v = new ViewPart();
    }
}
```

Тоже много писанины. Или есть еще способы? Или подход такой вовсе неверный, и компоненты надо проектировать иначе?

Вот [здесь](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/dagger-discuss/NecFfVCv4YQ/TCsniIMaMwAJ) вроде про то же самое спрашивают, пока без ответа.